# SQL DB2: I need to filter results based on query results

Tags: query, db2

I would need to get the `id`s for given input `employee_Id`s and given input `date`.

I need to query for employees who are enrolled on the given date or less then given date in the input.

Constraint: The employee shouldn't have the `disEnrolled` status on or before the given input date.

I have a table with below columns:

| id | date | status | employee_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | enrolled | 32456 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | disEnrolled | 32456 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | enrolled | 32457 |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 | enrolled | 32458 |

For example:

If the `employee_Id`s are `32456` and `32458` and given input date is `2021-01-01`, then expected result is `id` with the value `4` and `employee_Id` with the value `32458`.
The `employee_Id` with `32456` is not qualified because he has `disEnrolled` on or before given input date.

Below is what I have tried:

```
select a.ID 
from  EMPLOYEE  a
where (a.employee_id='34526' or a.employee_id = '32547')
  and (   (a.status= 'enrolled' and {d '2021-10-10'} >= p.date) 
       or (a.status NOT IN 'disEnrolled' and {d '2021-10-10'} <= a.date))
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition "the employee shouldn't have 'disEnrolled' status on or before the given input date" needs to be done using a NOT EXISTS condition. You can't really express that with a "simple" condition in the WHERE clause:

I think the following does what you want:

```
select e1.*
from employee e1
where e1.employee_id in (32456, 32458)
  and e1.status = 'enrolled'
  and e1.date <= date '2021-10-10'
  and not exists (select *
                  from employee e2
                  where e2.id <> e1.id
                    and e2.employee_id = e1.employee_id
                    and e2.status = 'disEnrolled'
                    and e2.date <= date '2021-10-10');
```

The first part of the WHERE condition selects those rows that fulfill the condition "*employees who are enrolled on the given date or less then given date in the input*"

The NOT EXISTS condition then applies the constraint "*the employee shouldn't have 'disEnrolled' status on or before the given input date*"

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=93bf7f8b9899bf6fa3411ab9849e2cfe)